# Formal decomposition of Hamiltonian into $A A^\ast$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + q$. Letting aside consideration of domains, I want to show that $H$ can be formally written as $H = A A^\ast$, where $A = -\frac{d}{dx} + \phi$ with some $\phi$ under the assumption that the equation $\psi'' + q \psi = 0$ has a positive solution.

My attempt: the adjoint of $A$ is $A^\ast = \frac{d}{dx} + \phi$ and
$A A^\ast = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} - \phi' + \phi^2$.

Now we assume $\psi$ is a solution of $\psi'' + q \psi = 0$.
Then setting $\phi = \frac{\psi'}{\psi}$ almost does it, but my problem is that $-\phi' + \phi^2$ then becomes $(\frac{(\psi')^2}{\psi^2} - \frac{\psi''}{\psi}) + \phi^2 = (\frac{(\psi')^2}{\psi^2} + q) + \frac{(\psi')^2}{\psi^2}$ where unfortunately the term $\frac{(\psi')^2}{\psi^2}$ doesnt cancel but occurs twice. On the other hand, setting $\phi = \frac{-\psi'}{\psi}$ would lead to the desired cancellation but then $-\phi'+\phi^2$ would become equal $-q$ instead of $q$. Where did I miscount and why is the positivity of the solution $\psi$ important?

Edit: Also I wonder what is the relation between $A A^\ast$ and $A^\ast A$?

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190341/2451

Comment: hi, thank you for the comment. Could you perhaps help me with my sign error which i cant overcome?

Comment: ok i guess i know my mistake: of course we assume $\psi$ is a solution of $-\psi'' + q \psi = 0$, the sign was missing in the assumption, not the calculation.